# Not able to recieve message after BIND_LISTENER deprecated

Tags: android, wear-os, deprecated

My app has been working fine until BIND_LISTENER deprecated and I have done any change needed but my app is not working. I send the message from wear successfully but nothing happen on the phone side.

My code on the wear (the sender):

```
private static final String WEARABLE_DATA_PATH = "/test/";

protected void sendMessageToHandheld(final String message) {

    final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient);
    nodes.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result) {
            final List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
            if (nodes != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
                    final Node node = nodes.get(i);
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleApiClient, node.getId(), WEARABLE_DATA_PATH, message.getBytes()).setResultCallback(
                            new ResultCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(@NonNull Result sendMessageResult) {
                                    if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to send message");
                                    } else{
                                        Log.d(TAG, "sendind message to handled: " + node.getDisplayName()
                                                + " - id: " + node.getId()
                                                + " - path: " + WEARABLE_DATA_PATH
                                                + " - message: " + message);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The listener service on the phone side:

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "ListenerService";
private static final String WEARABLE_DATA_PATH = "/test/";

public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Test");
}

public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    DataMap dataMap;
    Log.v(TAG, "DataMap received from watch: ");
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {

        // Check the data type
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            // Check the data path
            String path = event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();
            if (path.equals(WEARABLE_DATA_PATH)) {}
            dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem()).getDataMap();
            Log.v(TAG, "DataMap received on watch: " + dataMap);
        }
    }
}
```

}

My phone manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".wear_communication.DataLayerListenerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CHANNEL_EVENT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPrefix="/test/"
                android:scheme="wear" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Sending and Syncing Data**](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html)

> The Wearable Data Layer API, which is part of Google Play services, provides a communication channel for your handheld and wearable apps. The API consists of a set of data objects that the system can send and synchronize over the wire and listeners that notify your apps of important events with the data layer:
>
> - Data Items
> - Messages
> - Asset
> - WearableListenerService (for services)
> - DataListener (for foreground activities)
> - Channel

There are more information available about [Data Layer events](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html) and the use of [**`WearableListenerService`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService), and tags in the manifest. Android Studio has a [guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/bind-listener) with a summary of how to convert to the new API. The Android Wear samples also show best practices in the use of WearableListenerService, such as [DataLayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DataLayer) and [XYZTouristAttractions](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions). The changes needed are very small, and can be seen in this [git diff](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions/commit/f8bbd9f73e6b67944d55988c13b604954b2dd7f4) from one of the samples here.

Here are related documents and tutorials that can help you with Wearables and handheld device communication:

- [Deprecation of BIND_LISTENER with Android Wear APIs](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/deprecation-of-bindlistener.html)
- [Building Apps for Wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html)
- [Android Wear Development - Extend your Apps to Android Smartwatches](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-wear-development--ud875A)
- [How to start a Service (that samples light data) on a wearable from a handheld device?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676730/5995040)

These documents can help you understand how to replace BIND_LISTENER to the new  Fine-grained intent filter API.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did all of things that is needed (change gradle, code on wear, code on mobile, change mobile Manifest), but the mobile dont have a result from wear The wear show me that was send the Message, but nothing happens at mobile. And everything seems ok, like in code above.

I tried put onCreate() in mobile class, and the logcat showed me that the class is called.

Do you know what could be happening? Or what is missing?

P.S: sorry about my english, im Brazilian